# Restrict user to access admin Visualforce pages

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, custom-permission

In our managed package, we have Visualforce pages that are "public", but there are also some configuration pages that we want to make available only to "admin" user. In other word, we want to be able to give access to Visualforce pages only to user that have a specific Custom Permission, even if the managed package was installed for all users.

In order to do that, we created a Custom Pemission in a Permission-Set to give that access. Unfortunately, if the managed package is installed for all users, all users will have that Custom Permission (see [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177876/custom-permission-assign-to-all-users-by-default)).

Is there a way to fulfill our use case?

Comment: Are you including a perm set and checking for that permission set assignment in the vf controller. If not do so and if they do not have it then display an error div instead of the rest of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Eric said, including a perm set and checking for that permission set assignment in the vf controller works.